# Are there any more example regard how to use Updates?

Tags: telethon

I have been trying to improve my application by incorporating updates. However, the current documentation is very confusing on for example how updates would be structure for a chat or a channel.

Any advice on this topic would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things have changed a lot, but the [official Telethon documentation](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/basic/working-with-updates.html) probably explains them good enough now.

You can also view [single-file Telethon examples](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/tree/master/telethon_examples) or [real world Telethon projects](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/examples/projects-using-telethon.html). Maybe I'm a bit late for the answer but hopefully helps other people :)